# How to add "origin/master" to a local repo (and maybe the remote repo), although I already can push to the remote

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I have a local repository connected to a remote GitLab repository self-hosted by our company. I can push commits to the remote repo with a plain

```
git push
```

and I can see that the commits arrive in GitLab through GitLab's web interface.

But I suspect that *origin/master* does not exist, because when I try to view unpushed commits with

```
git log origin/master..master
```

I get the error message "*fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master..master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree*".

**How can I add *origin/master*, so that my git workflow works the "standard" way with a local *master* and a remote *origin/master*?** My local `.git/config` is already like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://mygitlab.local/MyGroup/MyProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    pushRemote = origin
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: @matt `git pull origin master` returns: "* branch master -> FETCH_HEAD. Already up to date." and afterwards `git log origin/master..head` still gives me the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: @matt After `git fetch`, `git show origin/master` returns my last commit: "commit eccf[...] (HEAD -> master, origin/master)\nAuthor: [...]"

Comment: @matt And NOW I _can_ do `git log origin/master..master`!!!

Comment: @matt Probably the `git fetch` sorted it.

Comment: @matt My git is 2.22. Too old?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219527/discussion-between-halloleo-and-matt).

Comment: To explicitly create `origin/foo`, you can always use `git fetch origin +refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/origin/foo`. As `remote.origin.fetch` is already set in your repo, `git fetch` or `git fetch origin master` should create `origin/master` automatically.